# Python selenium webdriver find_element_by_class_name not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, element

I am trying to get an element by its class name from its parent.
This method has worked in many cases, but for one class it does not work.
This is a simplified version of my code, showing how it doesn't work:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
moba_elem = browser.get("https://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/shaco-guide")

parent = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#content > div > div.mf-redesign > div.col-left > div.champ-pages__page.champ-pages__page--current.champ-pages__page--no-top-margin > div.browse-list > a.browse-list__item.player-grandmaster")
parent.find_element_by_class_name("browse-list__item__pic role-jungle")
```

What I am trying to do is separate each "lane" from each other. Here I am looking for the lane "jungle", but it cannot seem to find that class, even though I copied it from the inspect window.

Comment: You might be having trouble because `browse-list__item__pic role-jungle` is actually 2 class names. You might want to try converting it to a `css_selector` like `".browse-list__item__pic.role-jungle"`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by just searching for "role-jungle" instead of "browse-list__item__pic role-jungle"

so I did this when trying to find the element

```
parent.find_element_by_class_name("role-jungle")
```